# Grails 2.3.8 disable an action in production environment only

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I have an application in which I would like to create an action that is only available in development and test environments, but not in production.  Currently I am using the environments inside the action as such:

```
    def superSecretAction(){
    Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment {
        development{
           // Do something super secret and exciting
        }
        test{
           // Do the same super secret and exciting thing.  
        }
        production{
            render ""
        }
    }

}
```

While this option works, I would really like to simply deny even being able to call this method to begin with.  I'm using `Spring Security`, and have an `interceptUrlMap` which I could conceivably create a separate map for production as another option, but I was hoping there was a way that I could just completely invalidate the action in production all together.

As I mentioned in the title, I'm running 2.3.8 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a number of options.  You could have a filter that checked the environment and responded however you need to based on that.  You could also only add the mapping the action conditionally with something like this:

```
import grails.util.Environment

class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
        if(Environment.current != Environment.PRODUCTION) {
           // put your mapping here...
        }

        // ...

        "/"(view:"/index")
        "500"(view:'/error')
    }
}
```